# ZK getting selected item from combobox

Tags: java, combobox, zk

I am trying to get selected value in combobox  but it returns as a ComboItem.How can I get value as string?

```
<zscript>
  <![CDATA[
    String[] months = { "Ada", "Basic", "C", "C++", "Cobol", "Forth",
            "Fortran", "Go", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp",
            "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme" };
  ListModel lmonths = new SimpleListModel(months);
]]></zscript>
                    <combobox id="searchCombo"
                        forward="onChange=onSearch" model="@{months}" >
<!-- 
                        <comboitem self="@{each='months'}"
                            label="@{months}" value="@{months}">
                        </comboitem>
 -->

                        </combobox>
```

And here my onSearch method

```
public void onSearch(ForwardEvent event) {


        System.out.println(searchCombo.getSelectedItem());


    prodevt.search(searchCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        filterCbox.setChecked(true);



        AnnotateDataBinder binder = (AnnotateDataBinder) win.getVariable(
                "binder", true);

        binder.loadAll();

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it like

```
searchCombo.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

ZK's databinding with combobox is very powerful,

i created a sample to sync select data from comboboxes and listbox

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" ?>
<zk>
<zscript>
  <![CDATA[
        String[] langs = { "ZK" ,"Ada", "Basic", "C", "C++", "Cobol", "Forth", 
                           "Fortran", "Go", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", 
                           "JavaScript","Lisp", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala",
                           "Scheme" 
                         };
        //(Optional) Default Select ZK 
    String things_i_have_selected = langs[0]; 
    ]]></zscript>
<hlayout>
    <combobox model="@{langs}" selectedItem="@{things_i_have_selected}" />

    <combobox model="@{langs}" selectedItem="@{things_i_have_selected}" />

    <listbox model="@{langs}" selectedItem="@{things_i_have_selected}"  
             rows="5" width="400px">
        <listitem self="@{each=String}">
            <listcell label="@{String}"></listcell>
        </listitem>
    </listbox>
</hlayout>
</zk>
```

[image: I Love Data Binding]

what i want to say is that you don't need to get the selection item's value :)

Reference

1. [ZK Demo](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/data_binding)
2. [ZK Essentials#Implementing Data Binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Displaying_Information_in_a_Grid_Using_Data_Binding/Implementing_Data_Binding)

Answer (score 1):

searchCombo.getSelectedItem().getValue() --> get value of selected ComboItem

searchCombo.getSelectedItem().getLabel() --> get text of selected ComboItem